# Symfony 2 AngularJs Redirect to https

Tags: angularjs, symfony, redirect, https

I have to redirect all urls to https. I use an angularJs app with symfony 2 .
I'm working with xampp and i edited security.yml by adding access control :

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CALL_CENTER, ROLE_IT, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN], requires_channel: https }
```

i added a virtual host in httpd-vhost.cong to enable ssl but i received a 404 error.

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
```